# Sampling from a database

Tags: sampling

I am conducting a research study about breastfeedding. I receive a whole database of subjects which are suitable to my research. I have had to call each individual to ask for their approval to participate in the study since it also requieres the participation of their bosses and one co-worker. This means that I can only conduct research on individuals which boss and co-worker are willing to participate. I have receive several notifications of individuals who can not participate due to several reasons. From this standpoint my list of potential participants have been reduced. Is this type of sampling valid from a statistical perspective? My sample will be composed of approximately 30 individuals.

Comment: The good news: the answer will depend on the type of analysis you wish to do with these 30 individuals. The bad news: there are not too many questions you can answer with such data.

Comment: I was thinking about a regression analysis. Which other analysis may I conduct with such a small sample?

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to draw a sample the the sampling is less probabilistic and henceforth be less reliable. It is also affected for statistical analysis also. I am fully agreed with JohnRos comment. I think you can make inference from the sample data but you may not great scope to analysis the data. That's all from me.